# Prevent multiple application instances after Windows restarts

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have some applications, like Outlook, in my Startup folder so they run whenever my PC starts.

Now when Windows 10 installs updates and restarts itself, I come back to my desktop and have 2 instances out Outlook running. One from the Startup folder, and another because Windows restores any applications that were running at the time it shut down.

Is there any way to make it so only one instance will launch?

My PCs are all running Windows 10 1709 Pro, and exhibit this behavior for both Domain Accounts and personal Microsoft Accounts.

Comment: Navigate through `Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options -> Privacy`.  Once you are there, select **Off** for `Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart.`

Comment: I don't have that option, only `Show account details (e.g. email address) on sign-in screen.` I am using a Domain account to sign in to Windows.

Comment: Needless to say, that makes a big difference regarding any proposed solutions.  It would be wise to edit your question and add pertinent information like that, including your variety of Windows 10 (Pro, Enterprise, or Education) as well as the version and build numbers from `Right-click > Start > Run > winver`

Comment: Well it does it for both Domain and Microsoft Accounts on my work PC and PCs at home, I'm just at work at the moment and only have access to it.

Comment: At the very least, what I described should work on your home PC with your Microsoft account.  I have the same configuration on my home network (Windows 10 Pro version 1709 utilizing a Microsoft account), and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook, the shortcut in startup should [include in the command line `/recycle`](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm), which prevents opening a second window.

This is not a complete answer, I realize, just for Outlook.